# flake8 doesn't report mixed-case function names

Tags: python, pep8

I created a short script called `test_pep8.py` containing the following:

```
def myFunc():
    return None
```

I would expect flake8 to produce a warning about mixed case function names. But, flake8 reports no warnings:

```
> flake8 --verbose test_pep8.py
checking test_pep8.py
```

I then ran pep8 directly on the file and got the same result:

```
import pep8
checker = pep8.Checker('test_pep8.py')
checker.check_all()
> 0
```

Checking out the pep8 library, I noticed this set of default ignores:

```
DEFAULT_IGNORE = 'E121,E123,E126,E226,E24,E704'
```

But, incorrect function naming doesn't appear to be listed.

Here's my flake8 version info:

```
> flake8 --version
2.3.0 (pep8: 1.6.2, pyflakes: 0.8.1, mccabe: 0.3) CPython 2.6.6 on Linux
```

Anyone know why flake8 is not reporting this pep8 violation? Thanks!

EDIT:
Just spotted this module: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pep8-naming
Is pep8 naming now enforced by a different library? I seem to remember pep8 covering that before, but I could be mistaken.

pep8-naming does seem to be the solution:

```
> flake8 --verbose test_pep8.py
checking test_pep8.py
test_pep8.py:5:5: N802 function name should be lowercase
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to install [`pep8-naming`](https://pypi.org/project/pep8-naming/)

```
pip install pep8-naming
```

and you should also include it in your pip `requirements.txt`

```
flake8
pep8-naming
```

Additional plugins/extensions for flake8 can be found at https://pypi.org/search/?q=flake8-